# Tomcat using RC4 ciphers when not present in "ciphers" list

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat7

We're running SSL through a tomcat7 instance that also requires a PCI scan.  The SSL ciphers have consistently been a pain and the PCI compliance company the client uses doesn't have much in the way of information besides "refer to vendor documentation."

The latest issue is that tomcat is supposedly supporting RC4 cipher algorithms.  Specifically, the scan is stating that tomcat is accepting SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, and SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5.  The problem is that we're only allows TLS and the few ciphers we're telling it to use are none of the ones they list as being bad.  Our connector block is:

```
<Connector address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" keystoreFile="XXXX" 
    keystorePass="XXXX" keyAlias="XXXX"
    ciphers="TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" />
```

I ran an online scan of the IP and it also showed up some RC4 ciphers.

Is there something I'm missing?  I'm admittedly a little ignorant about the various layers of how this all works.

Thanks

Comment: Do you perhaps have a proxy or load balancer in front of your Tomcat instance that is being inspected by the scans?

Comment: Nope.  It's going directly to tomcat.  Tomcat is binding directly to the IP (well, technically it's NAT'ed).

Comment: Scans are reporting that the following ciphers are supported (TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA).   I'm telling tomcat to only use TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

Comment: Yes.  I had some ciphers listed in my Tomcat config that weren't available/enabled in Java on my server.  If you have a cipher listed that Java doesn't like, it just reverts back to the default list of ciphers, which is annoying.  This bit of code helped me figure out what was valid on my machine: http://markmail.org/message/zn4namfhypyxum23